# Python Tkinter Popup frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a tkinter gui for POS and I want to check if my codes are correct? Whenever I click "button5" it should popup a frame of that menu. Without the functionality, it works fine as expected but whenever I click the button some of the buttons disappeared. Is there something I missed to write? Appreciate your advise. Thank you[image]

```
def menu():
main_win.withdraw()
global m
m = Toplevel()
page18 = Menu(m)
m.geometry("1366x768")
m.resizable(0, 0)
m.title("ADMIN Mode")
m.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW")
m.mainloop()

class Menu:
def __init__(self, top=None):
    top.geometry("1366x768")
    top.resizable(0, 0)
    top.title("Invoices")
    self.background = Label(m)
    self.background.place(relx=0, rely=0, width=1366, height=768)
    self.bg_img = PhotoImage(file="./images/bg.png")
    self.background.configure(image=self.bg_img)
    self.menu_classic()


def menu_classic(self):
    global frame1
    frame1 = Label(m, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
    # Displaying the frame1 in row 0 and column 0
    frame1.place(width=950, height=760)

    self.label = Label(frame1)
    self.label.pack()
    self.labelImage = Image.open("./images/menu/menu.png")
    self.labelResized = self.labelImage.resize((950, 760), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.labelImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.labelResized)
    self.label.configure(image=self.labelImage)
    self.label.configure(background="#ffcc70")

    self.button1 = Button(frame1)
    self.button1.place(relx=0, rely=0.1, width=168, height=60)
    self.button1.configure(relief="flat",
                           overrelief="flat",
                           activebackground="#666666",
                           cursor="hand2",
                           # foreground="#ffffff",
                           background="#3d3d3d",
                           borderwidth="0")
    self.img1 = Image.open("./images/menu/menu_milkteaclassic_button.png")
    self.resized1 = self.img1.resize((168, 60), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized1)
    self.button1.configure(image=self.img1)

    self.button2 = Button(frame1)
    self.button2.place(relx=0, rely=0.175, width=168, height=60)
    self.button2.configure(relief="flat",
                           overrelief="flat",
                           activebackground="#666666",
                           cursor="hand2",
                           # foreground="#ffffff",
                           background="#3d3d3d",
                           borderwidth="0")
    self.img2 = Image.open("./images/menu/menu_cream_button1.png")
    self.resized2 = self.img2.resize((168, 60), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized2)
    self.button2.configure(image=self.img2)
    # self.button2.configure(command=menu_cream)

    self.button3 = Button(frame1)
    self.button3.place(relx=0, rely=0.25, width=168, height=60)
    self.button3.configure(relief="flat",
                           overrelief="flat",
                           activebackground="#666666",
                           cursor="hand2",
                           # foreground="#ffffff",
                           background="#3d3d3d",
                           borderwidth="0")
    self.img3 = Image.open("./images/menu/menu_fruit_button1.png")
    self.resized3 = self.img3.resize((168, 60), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.img3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized3)
    self.button3.configure(image=self.img3)
    # self.button3.configure(command=menu_fruit)

    self.button4 = Button(frame1)
    self.button4.place(relx=0, rely=0.325, width=168, height=60)
    self.button4.configure(relief="flat",
                           overrelief="flat",
                           activebackground="#666666",
                           cursor="hand2",
                           # foreground="#ffffff",
                           background="#3d3d3d",
                           borderwidth="0")
    self.img4 = Image.open("./images/menu/menu_yakult_button1.png")
    self.resized4 = self.img4.resize((168, 60), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized4)
    self.button4.configure(image=self.img4)
    # self.button4.configure(command=menu_yakult)

    self.button5 = Button(frame1)
    self.button5.place(relx=0.205, rely=0.18, width=240, height=200)
    self.button5.configure(relief="flat",
                           overrelief="flat",
                           activebackground="#666666",
                           cursor="hand2",
                           # foreground="#ffffff",
                           background="#3d3d3d",
                           borderwidth="0")
    self.img5 = Image.open("./images/menu/classic.png")
    self.resized5 = self.img5.resize((240, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.img5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized5)
    self.button5.configure(image=self.img5)
    self.button5.configure(command=self.classic)

    self.button6 = Button(frame1)
    self.button6.place(relx=0.465, rely=0.18, width=240, height=200)
    self.button6.configure(relief="flat",
                           overrelief="flat",
                           activebackground="#666666",
                           cursor="hand2",
                           # foreground="#ffffff",
                           background="#3d3d3d",
                           borderwidth="0")
    self.img6 = Image.open("./images/menu/wintermelon.png")
    self.resized6 = self.img6.resize((240, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.img6 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized6)
    self.button6.configure(image=self.img6)
    #self.button6.configure(command=self.classic)

    self.button7 = Button(frame1)
    self.button7.place(relx=0.725, rely=0.18, width=240, height=200)
    self.button7.configure(relief="flat",
                           overrelief="flat",
                           activebackground="#666666",
                           cursor="hand2",
                           # foreground="#ffffff",
                           background="#3d3d3d",
                           borderwidth="0")
    self.img7 = Image.open("./images/menu/honey dew.png")
    self.resized7 = self.img7.resize((240, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.img7 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized7)
    self.button7.configure(image=self.img7)
    # self.button7.configure(command=menu_yakult)

    self.button8 = Button(frame1)
    self.button8.place(relx=0.205, rely=0.45, width=240, height=200)
    self.button8.configure(relief="flat",
                           overrelief="flat",
                           activebackground="#666666",
                           cursor="hand2",
                           # foreground="#ffffff",
                           background="#3d3d3d",
                           borderwidth="0")
    self.img8 = Image.open("./images/menu/okinawa.png")
    self.resized8 = self.img8.resize((240, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.img8 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized8)
    self.button8.configure(image=self.img8)
    # self.button8.configure(command=menu_yakult)

    self.button9 = Button(frame1)
    self.button9.place(relx=0.465, rely=0.45, width=240, height=200)
    self.button9.configure(relief="flat",
                           overrelief="flat",
                           activebackground="#666666",
                           cursor="hand2",
                           # foreground="#ffffff",
                           background="#3d3d3d",
                           borderwidth="0")
    self.img9 = Image.open("./images/menu/dark choco.png")
    self.resized9 = self.img9.resize((240, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.img9 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized9)
    self.button9.configure(image=self.img9)
    # self.button9.configure(command=menu_yakult)

    self.button10 = Button(frame1)
    self.button10.place(relx=0.725, rely=0.45, width=240, height=200)
    self.button10.configure(relief="flat",
                            overrelief="flat",
                            activebackground="#666666",
                            cursor="hand2",
                            # foreground="#ffffff",
                            background="#3d3d3d",
                            borderwidth=0)
    self.img10 = Image.open("./images/menu/matcha.png")
    self.resized10 = self.img10.resize((240, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.img10 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized10)
    self.button10.configure(image=self.img10)
    # self.button10.configure(command=menu_yakult)

    self.button11 = Button(frame1)
    self.button11.place(relx=0.205, rely=0.72, width=240, height=200)
    self.button11.configure(relief="flat",
                            overrelief="flat",
                            activebackground="#666666",
                            cursor="hand2",
                            # foreground="#ffffff",
                            background="#3d3d3d",
                            borderwidth="0")
    self.img11 = Image.open("./images/menu/hokaido.png")
    self.resized11 = self.img11.resize((240, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.img11 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized11)
    self.button11.configure(image=self.img11)
    # self.button11.configure(command=menu_yakult)

    self.button12 = Button(frame1)
    self.button12.place(relx=0.465, rely=0.72, width=240, height=200)
    self.button12.configure(relief="flat",
                            overrelief="flat",
                            activebackground="#666666",
                            cursor="hand2",
                            # foreground="#ffffff",
                            background="#3d3d3d",
                            borderwidth="0")
    self.img12 = Image.open("./images/menu/taro.png")
    self.resized12 = self.img12.resize((240, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.img12 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized12)
    self.button12.configure(image=self.img12)
    # self.button12.configure(command=menu_yakult)


    self.ordelist()

def ordelist(self):
    frame2 = Label(m, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
    # Displaying the frame1 in row 0 and column 0
    frame2.place(relx=0.695, rely=0, width=417, height=765)

    self.label1 = Label(frame2)
    self.label1.pack()
    self.labelImage1 = Image.open("./images/menu/orderlist.png")
    self.labelResized1 = self.labelImage1.resize((417, 765), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.labelImage1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.labelResized1)
    self.label1.configure(image=self.labelImage1)
    self.label1.configure(background="#ffcc70")

def classic(self):
    frame3 = Label(frame1, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
    # Displaying the frame1 in row 0 and column 0
    frame3.place(relx=0.695, rely=0, width=600, height=700)

    self.label2 = Label(frame3)
    self.label2.pack()
    self.labelImage2 = Image.open("./images/menu/menu 2/classic milktea.png")
    self.labelResized2 = self.labelImage2.resize((600, 700), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    self.labelImage2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.labelResized2)
    self.label2.configure(image=self.labelImage2)
    self.label2.configure(background="#ffcc70")
```

Comment: the first thing I've noticed is function menu references `main_win` but there is no instantiation of it. I presume it's a`Tk` object. Could you show how  `main_win` is defined?

Comment: @Derek I got it already... I need to change this to "frame3 = Label(m, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)" but how can I close the frame to open another frame? Thank you

Comment: `m.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW")` needs a function to call in order to close `m`
`m.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", m.closer)` for example

Comment: Also `from tkinter import *` is not good as it may - in fact it has a naming conflict. Menu is a `tkinter` object name. It would be much better to use `import tkinter as tk` and prepend `tkinter` objects with `tk.`

Comment: No probs, Happy coding.